# How to record audio while OpenCv has enabled camera

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, pyaudio

I want to record the audio and store the same while analyzing the emotion using Opencv. But unfortunately, the audio which is being recorded is of minimal length and the voice is also not clear. I want to analyze the voice emotion too for which I need to audio. Could somebody help me in resolving the same?

```
def main():


  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)


  p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
  stream = p.open(format=audio_format, channels=channels,rate=16000, input=True,frames_per_buffer=1024)


  start_time = time.time()
  aud = True


  while aud:
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    data = stream.read(chunk, exception_on_overflow = False)
    frames.append(data)

    if not ret:
        break

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors= 5, flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    result = DeepFace.analyze(img_path = frame , actions = ["emotion"], enforce_detection=False,detector_backend='ssd')

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:

        if w > 130: #trick: ignore small faces

            draw_border(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 105),4, 15, 10) ## draw rectangle around face.
            detected_face = frame[int(y):int(y+h), int(x):int(x+w)] #crop detected face
            detected_face = cv2.cvtColor(detected_face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #transform to gray scale
            detected_face = cv2.resize(detected_face, (48, 48)) #resize to 48x48
            img_pixels = img_to_array(detected_face)
            img_pixels = np.expand_dims(img_pixels, axis = 0)
            img_pixels /= 255 #pixels are in scale of [0, 255]. normalize all pixels in scale of [0, 1]




    emotion = result["dominant_emotion"]

    txt = str(emotion)

    cv2.putText(frame,txt,(50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,255),3)


    cv2.imshow(file, frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        aud=False
        break
      
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open('/Users/xyz/Documents/Audio/wv.wav', 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(1)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(audio_format))

wf.setframerate(sample_rate)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16     Change this stream = p.open(format=audio_format, to stream = p.open(format=sample_format,

Comment: my audio_format is already pyaudio.paInt16. but still no good. If I run only the audio part then it is capturing the actual audio

Comment: You have this import wave?

Comment: Yes, I have already imported that too

Comment: what about this while aud: to while cap.isOpened():

Comment: done that too but no good. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250923/discussion-between-toyota-supra-and-sourav-singh).

Comment: sample_width = p.get_sample_size(FORMAT)
stream.stop_stream()

Comment: tried them too but still no luck.